# Can I use CUDA with a non-NVIDIA GPU?

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I'm looking for a way to run CUDA programs on a system with no NVIDIA GPU.

I tried to install MCUDA and gpuOcelot but seemed to have some problems with the installation.

I have gone through the answers given in [How to run CUDA without a GPU using a software implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753735/how-to-run-cuda-without-a-gpu-using-a-software-implementation). The answers there recommended changing the hardware of the system, using an emulator (which is now deprecated) or switching to OpenCL. None of these adequately answered my requirement

Answer (score 6):

CUDA is an NVIDIA proprietary technology, and the only current, useful, and fully functional implementation available requires a system with a supported NVIDIA GPU. If you don't have that (and it seems you don't) then there is no solution to your problem.