# Can I make a Huggingface trainer work with an Intel GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, tensorrt, huggingface-evaluate

I am trying to fine-tune a language model using the Huggingface libraries, following their [guide](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training) (with another model and different data, but I don't think this is the crucial point). I am doing this on a Jupyter notebook inside VSCode. My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

Apparently, my laptop does not have a Nvidia GPU: running
`sudo lspci -v | less`
reveals that my VGA controller is an Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 (Iris Xe Graphics).

When trying to run the last line `trainer.train()`, the kernel crashes. When reducing the batch size to 1, it works, but it is exceeeedingly slooow... (more than 1000 hours expected)... It seems to run on the **C**PU (also from Intel). Is there any way to make use of my Intel **G**PU to make it faster?

Right now I am using Google Colab notebooks and it works ok for me, but I am still interested to know if there is a way to make it work on my own GPU.

**Old version of the question for reference (partly solved already)**

I am trying to fine-tune a language model using the Huggingface libraries, following their [guide](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training) (with another model and different data, but I don't think this is the crucial point). I am doing this on a Jupyter notebook inside VSCode. My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

When importing the evaluate library, the following message appears:

> 2024-02-02 17:18:24.904495: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
> 2024-02-02 17:18:24.934699: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
> To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
> 2024-02-02 17:18:25.505165: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
> /home/sg/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/cuda/**init**.py:628: UserWarning: Can't initialize NVML
> warnings.warn("Can't initialize NVML")

Later on, I can still do
`metric = evaluate.load('accuracy')`,
so the import seemed to work anyway.

Everything goes on fine, until
`trainer.train()`
where the kernel crashes. The Jupyter log lists the previously cited message as reason for this.

Apparently, my laptop does not have a Nvidia GPU: running
`sudo lspci -v | less`
reveals a lot of Intel stuff, one Realtek and one KIOXIA device.

After having read a lot today, I get the impression that the evaluate library requires tensorflow, tensorflow requires cuda, and cuda requires a Nvidia GPU. Is my impression correct? Can I make it work anyway, and how? (I know I could probably use a Google Colab notebook, but I would still like to do it locally if possible.)
One answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753735/how-to-run-cuda-without-a-gpu-using-a-software-implementation) pointed out the existence of OpenCL - would that be of any use in my situation?

Trying to solve this problem was essentially today's work for me. Most relevantly:

- I updated tensorflow and a bunch of other packages to the most recent version.
- I followed the instructions [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) to install the cuda toolkit. I also adapted the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables.
- I installed nvidia-tensorrt and also adapted LD_LIBRARY_PATH. But I am slightly unsure if I did it right: I appended the path /home/sg/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorrt which is where I found the libnvinfer file.

Comment: In the meantime, I have been able to get rid of the first part of the issue, namely the error messages when importing evaluate. To achieve this, I uninstalled tensorflow, torch, and the huggingface libraries, and reinstalled the ROCm version of torch and then the huggingface libraries. However, the kernel still crashes when attempting to train.